# rosdep won't install joint_state_publisher

Tags: rosdep, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ rosdep install joint_state_publisher
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
joint_state_publisher: Unsupported OS [mint]
```

would it help if i moved to ubuntu from mint? else what is the solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71368/rosdep-won%27t-install-joint_state_publisher/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seem to be a problem detecting recent mint versions: [rospkg mint issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/25)

Related: [rosdep issues containing 'mint'](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/search?q=mint&ref=cmdform&type=Issues)

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1